# Play Framework 2.1 is returning HTTP Headers instead of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, caching, playframework, http-headers, playframework-2.1

When requesting a public asset in Play Framework 2.1, I get HTTP Headers instead of JavScript/asset source.

I have this problem in Safari on iPad, it happens often and on random JavaScript files.

In my index.html I request some js files:

```
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/libs/moment.js")'></script>
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/libs/underscore.js")'></script>
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/libs/backbone.js")'></script>
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bridge/component.js")'></script>
```

In console I run Play in dev mode

```
play run
```

When I request I file in Safari I get response showing HTTP headers instead of JavaScript code. My question is what can cause this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this problem using this project:

https://github.com/huntc/angular-seed-play

Can you please try this project and see if you get the same result. Also can you please try other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your screen shot that you are showing the debug console which typically shows headers etc....  You need to expand the actual browser window to see the response content.

Answer (score 0):

We are experimenting the same issue on an iPad app.. It seems closing linked to Playframework assets & iPad.

We should create an issue on play, fact is it is hardly reproductible.

We are also using Play 2.1